# adding users to username.htpasswd

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a requirement to pull data from a csv file that states males should be added to username.htpasswd while using their color as as their password. I'm pulling the data from a csv file and I wrote this small script on the command line.

I ended it with 'done' but the command line is I guess in interactive mode?

Here's the script I wrote:

```
cut -d, -f1,4,7 file.csv | while IFS="," read -r username gender color; do if [[ "$gender == "m" ]]; then htpasswd -c -b /root/"$username".htpasswd "$username" "$color" fi; done
```

I was able to get the script working without checking for gender. But since that is a requirement I'm not really sure how to incorporate a proper if statement within my script.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"$gender` is missing a closing quote, should be `"$gender"`. Put a shebang on your script and paste it at https://shellcheck.net

Comment: @jetchisel that website is clutch and helped me fix my script! Thank you so much for putting me on!